# How do I generate a diagonal matrix in KDB?

Tags: kdb

I'm trying to generate a matrix such that:

- Diagonal elements are 1
- All other elements are 0.5

I'm trying to modify the example for the identity matrix:

```
{x=/:x}@til 4
```

to squeeze in my special function:

```
shrinkfn: {$[x=y;1;0.5]}
```

but I'm struggling. What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
q)m:{x=/:x}@til 4
q)?'[m;1;0.5]
1   0.5 0.5 0.5
0.5 1   0.5 0.5
0.5 0.5 1   0.5
0.5 0.5 0.5 1
```

Alternative method:

https://code.kx.com/phrases/matrix/#identity-matrix-of-order-x

```
q)f:{(2#x)#1f,x#.5}
q)f 5
1   0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5
0.5 1   0.5 0.5 0.5
0.5 0.5 1   0.5 0.5
0.5 0.5 0.5 1   0.5
0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 1
```

Explanation:

we can use the the following notation to create a matrix:

```
q)3 3#til 9
0 1 2
3 4 5
6 7 8
```

when the list runs out of elements it repeats:

```
q)3 2#til 4
0 1
2 3
0 1
```

with 5 by 5 matrix the the next diagonal is always 6 places, thus the list is of length 6:

```
q)5 5#1 .5 .5 .5 .5 .5
1   0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5
0.5 1   0.5 0.5 0.5
0.5 0.5 1   0.5 0.5
0.5 0.5 0.5 1   0.5
0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 1
```

Comment: Oh, this is amazing, thanks! In the second example (identity matrix of order x), can you briefly add a comment explaining what's happening? The code is a bit mysterious...

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of variety another option is:

```
{0.5 1f x=/:x}til 4
```

This will use the boolean lists (0 or 1b) to index into our two element array and distribute the values accordingly along the matrix.

```
q){x=/:x}til 4
1000b
0100b
0010b
0001b
q){0.5 1f x=/:x}til 4
1   0.5 0.5 0.5
0.5 1   0.5 0.5
0.5 0.5 1   0.5
0.5 0.5 0.5 1
```